# PHP Generating email body

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to make my php page automatically generate an email and send it to a recipient if their account was changed, and list the account changes.

What I have works, but only if I ONLY change the login name of the user, it doesn't work if anything else is changed.

If I only change the login name of the user, the email is sent and lists the change in the body of the email.

If anything else is changed, the email is sent, but only has the table headers and nothing else (including the login name).

Here is what I have:

`Generate list of things that were changed based on input results vs database`

```
        $ret = $db->query("SELECT * from Users WHERE LoginName='$loginNameFromPost' LIMIT 1;");
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
            //list changes
            if(strcmp($row['LoginName'],$loginNameFromPost) != 0) {
                $lnchange = 1;
            }
            if(strcmp($row['Email'],$emailFromPost) != 0) {
                $emchange = 1;
            }
            if(strcmp($row['DisplayName'],$displayNameFromPost) != 0) {
                $dnchange = 1;
            }
            if(strcmp($row['Level'],$levelFromPost) != 0) {
                $lchange = 1;
            }
            if(!empty($passwordFromPost)) {
                $pwchange = 1;
            }           
        }
```

Anything that changed would have a value of `1`.

`Generate email body`

```
$message = '
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Changes to your account - TRG Repair Log</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Some changes were made to your account by an administrator.</p>
                <table style="border:1px solid black;">';
                $message .= '<tr>
                        <th>Setting</th><th>New Setting</th>
                    </tr>';
                if($lnchange == 1) {
                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td>Login Name</td><td>'.$loginNameFromPost.'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                if($emchange == 1) {
                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td>Email</td><td>'.$emailFromPost.'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                if($dnchange == 1) {
                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td>Display Name</td><td>'.$displayNameFromPost.'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                if($lchange == 1) {
                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td>Clearance Level</td><td>'.$levelFromPost.'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                if($pwchange == 1) {
                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td>Password</td><td>Contact '.$_SESSION['tech'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }

                $message .= '</table>
            </body>
        </html>
        ';
```

This uses `if` statements and concatenates strings if the value had been changed.

I'm very stuck here, and not sure why it isn't working. I've been trying different things for almost an hour.

Clear up confusion:
I have an html form that is connected to the script above.

Lets say I go to my form, and change ONLY the LoginName of any user in the database - the email is sent and in the email it has the changed LoginName listed in the table.

Lets say i go to the same form, and change the LoginName and also the Display Name (Or email, password, level, etc) - the email is sent, but in the email it only has the headers of the table that is suppose to list all the changes that were made. No other information is listed in the table.

My database headers:

[image]

POSTed variables:

```
    $loginNameFromPost = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['loginname']);
    $passwordFromPost = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['password']);
    $emailFromPost = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['email']);
    $displayNameFromPost = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['displayname']);
    $levelFromPost = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['level']);
```

HTML Form view:

[image]

Results if ONLY LoginName is changed:

[image]

Results if ANYTHING ELSE (Besides LoginName) is changed (Same result if LoginName is changed along with anything else):

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `LIMIT 1`? Beyond what it obviously does.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth It shouldn't ever make a difference, but in rare cases where an admin may have made a duplicate LoginName by accident, its handled.

Comment: Can you please `echo` all your `$row['Email'],$emailFromPost`, `$row['Email'],$emailFromPost`, ... comparisons?

Comment: It might help us to see the code of the form to make sure the names are correct, especially since you said it works correctly if the `LoginName` is changed yet your example shows a successful Display Name change.

Comment: @fislerdata Your comment helped me figure out where I went wrong. I meant to set the query to search by uniqueID, but I had it searching by the name supplied in the POST that was being changed `not sure how I managed that one`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, answer your own question and accept it. I'm sure you're not the only one that will have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was my query was searching by the POST value that was being changed.

`$ret = $db->query("SELECT * from Users WHERE LoginName='$loginNameFromPost' LIMIT 1;");`

I needed to change $loginNameFromPost to my variable for the uniqueID.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be hard to verify without seeing the database, but your php looks fine. What I expect is happening is that those fields aren't spelt quite how you have them in the query string. e.g.

`$row['Email']` could actually be `$row['email']`

This would explain why your php looks fine but it's not working.

Comment: Updated my post with an image of the database headers.